# Conditioning on Regex

Tags: python, regex, string, conditional-statements

I have several strings from which I need to extract the block numbers. The block numbers are of the format type "3rd block" , "pine block" ,"block 2" and "block no 4". Please note that is just the format type and the numbers could change. I have added them in OR conditions .

The problem is that at times the regex extracts the previous word connected to something else like "main phase block 2" would mean I need "block 2" to be extracted . Using re.search causes the 1st result to turn up and there are even limitations of "OR".

What I want is to add exceptions or condition my regex with something like

1. if 1 or 2 digits (like 23 , 3 ,6 ,7 etc) occur before the word "block", extract "block" with the word following "block".

   Eg :

   ```
    string = "rmv clusters phase 2 block 1 , flat no 209 dev." #extract "block 1" and not "2 block".
   ```
2. if words "phase , apartment or building" come before "block", extract word that follows block (irrespective of whether its a number or word)
   Eg:

   ```
    string 2 = "sky line apartments block 2 chandra layout" #extract "block 2" and not "apartments block"
   ```

Here is what I have done. But I've got no idea about adding conditions.

```
 p = re.compile(r'(block[^a-z]\s\d*)|(\w+\sblock[^a-z])|(block\sno\s\d+)')
    q = p.search(str)
```

this is a part of an entire function.

Comment: You seem to contradict yourself on 1) if digits come before block, extract block with them, but comment says extract block 1 and not 2 block. ???

Comment: Why can't you write different regexes with priority. If a higher priority regex matches do a findall() for that.

Comment: sorry it was a typo :P @AaronHall editing it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on Python 2.7 and 3.3.

```
import re

strings = ("rmv clusters phase 2 block 1 , flat no 209 dev." 
           "sky line apartments block 2 chandra layout"
           "foo bar 99 block baz") # tests rule 1.
```

Here's the rules you stated you wanted:

1. if 1 or 2 digits (like 23 , 3 ,6 ,7 etc) occur before the word "block", extract "block" with the word following "block".
2. if words "phase , apartment or building" come before "block", extract word that follows block (irrespective of whether its a number or word). * I'm inferring you want the word block too.

So

```
regex = re.compile(r'''
           (?:\d{1,2}\s)(block\s\w*) # rule 1
             |   # or
           (?:(phase|apartment|building).*?)(block\s\w+) # rule 2
             ''', re.X)

found = regex.finditer(strings)

for i in found:
    print(i.groups())
```

prints:

```
(None, 'phase', '1')
(None, 'apartment', '2')
('block baz', None, None)
```

None is the default for a group if not found, so, you can pick a preference and allow the short-cutting `or` to return the first if it's non-empty, or the second if the first *is* empty (i.e. evaluates as False in Python's boolean contexts).

```
>>> found = regex.finditer(strings)
>>> for i in found:
...   print(i.group(1) or i.group(3))
... 
1
2
block baz
```

So to put this thing into a simple function:

```
def block(str):
    regex = re.compile(r'''
               (?:\d{1,2}\s)(block\s\w*) # rule 1
                 |   # or
               (?:(phase|apartment|building).*?)(block\s\w+) # rule 2
                 ''', re.X)
    match = regex.search(str)
    if not match:
        return ''
    else:
        return match.group(1) or match.group(3) or ''
```

usage:

```
>>> block("foo bar 99 block baz")
'block baz'
>>> block("sky line apartments block 2 chandra layout")
'block 2'
```

Comment: can i combine this with my original regex?? and why is it returning "apartments" and "2" ??

Comment: That's part of the non-capturing group, you can ignore that if you want. I'll add a bit more.

Comment: i'm using it as a function and getting an indent error.. could u come on python chat group?

Answer (score 1):

```
>> import re
>>> string = "rmv clusters phase 2 block 1 , flat no 209 dev."
>>> string2 = "sky line apartments block 2 chandra layout"
>>> print re.findall(r'block\s+\d+', string)
['block 1']
>>> print re.findall(r'block\s+\d+', string2)
['block 2']
```

Comment: i do not want a hard code.. The string is variable and i need to apply the regex on many strings . So a function would be preferable..

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you write multiple regexes? See the following snippet in python3

```
def getBlockMatch(string):
    import re
    p1Regex = re.compile('block\s+\d+')
    p2Regex = re.compile('(block[^a-z]\s\d*)|(\w+\sblock[^a-z])|(block\sno\s\d+)')
    if p1Regex.search(string) is not None:
        return p1Regex.findall(string)
    else:
        return p2Regex.findall(string)

string = "rmv clusters phase 2 block 1 , flat no 209 dev."
print(getBlockMatch(string))

string = "sky line apartments block 2 chandra layout"
print(getBlockMatch(string))
```

Outputs:

```
['block 1']
['block 2']
```